# Notice: wp_get_http is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.4.0!

Tags: plugins

How can I fix this error:

```
Notice: wp_get_http is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.4.0! Use WP_Http instead. in C:\...\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3828
```

I try to use Importer and get these error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known core issue, see e.g. [this ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34679). There is work done fixing this issue by a complete rewrite of the importer, but no ETA for it yet.

For now as this is only a Notice you can safely ignore it for the time being.

Comment: Nice research. I'm not surprised it hasn't been fixed yet. Give it another year or two of people pushing.

Comment: It's one of the more understandable times of nothing happening. Something like: "Why waste time on a small bugfix when there is a whole rewrite already being worked on that will also solve this"

Comment: Doesn't show via the ticket context.

Comment: @NathanPowell The very first comment?

Comment: Lol, github to the rescue? https://github.com/boonebgorges/wordpress-importer/pull/5

Comment: Very first comment over a year ago?